# How do you map column values onto another, but actually replace any existing values?

Tags: python, pandas

```
IDOne      Number    IDTwo    NewNumber
112        1         113    
115        2         144      79
114        3         132      32
115        4         114      66666 
116        5         115 
117        6         112
```

Output Desired:

```
IDOne      Number    IDTwo    NewNumber
112        1         113    
115        2         144      79
114        3         132      32
115        4         114      3 
116        5         115      4
117        6         112      1
```

I know how to replace empty values:

```
df['NewNumber'] = d['NewNumber'].fillna(df['IdOne'].map(dict(zip(df['IdTwo'], 
df['NewNumber']))))
```

Comment: Why are you mapping 115 to 4 instead of 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a dictionary from `IDOne` and `Number`, [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21.1/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) the values in `IDTwo` and use [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) to replace the missing values `NewNumber`:

```
d = df.set_index('IDOne').Number.to_dict()
# {112: 1, 115: 4, 114: 3, 116: 5, 117: 6}
df['NewNumber'] = df.IDTwo.map(d).combine_first(df.NewNumber)
```

---

```
print(df)

   IDOne  Number  IDTwo  NewNumber
0    112       1    113        NaN
1    115       2    144       79.0
2    114       3    132       32.0
3    115       4    114        3.0
4    116       5    115        4.0
5    117       6    112        1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge a dataframe onto itself. The problematic point is that 115 is duplicated in `IDOne`. According to the expected result, you want the last one instead of the first. So you can use:

```
df['NewNumber'] = df.merge(df.loc[~df.duplicated('IDOne', keep='last'),['IDOne', 'Number']],
                           left_on='IDTwo', right_on = 'IDOne', how='left'
                           )['Number_y'].combine_first(df['NewNumber'])
```

giving:

```
   IDOne  Number  IDTwo  NewNumber
0    112       1    113        NaN
1    115       2    144       79.0
2    114       3    132       32.0
3    115       4    114        3.0
4    116       5    115        4.0
5    117       6    112        1.0
```

If you wanted to keep the first value, you would use:

```
df['NewNumber'] = df.merge(df.loc[~df.duplicated('IDOne'),['IDOne', 'Number']],
                           left_on='IDTwo', right_on = 'IDOne', how='left'
                           )['Number_y'].combine_first(df['NewNumber'])
```

giving:

```
   IDOne  Number  IDTwo  NewNumber
0    112       1    113        NaN
1    115       2    144       79.0
2    114       3    132       32.0
3    115       4    114        3.0
4    116       5    115        2.0
5    117       6    112        1.0
```